# "Bad file descriptor" error, when using file descriptors of the socketpair function more than once

Tags: c, linux, sockets, unix, ipc

The following code sends messages from child processes to their parents using socket pairs.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MESSAGE "Hello"

int main()
{ 
    char message[100];
    int i, pidFork, sockets[2];

    /*
     *Trying to use a single socketpair function call
     *
     *if(socketpair(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0, sockets) == -1) {
     *   perror("Creating socketpair");
     *   exit(-1);
     *}
     */

    for(i=0; i<2; i++) { 

        if(socketpair(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0, sockets) == -1) {
            perror("Creating socketpair");
            exit(-1);
        }

        printf("i: %d\n", i);
        pidFork = fork();
        if (pidFork == -1) {
            perror("Creating child process");
            exit(-1);
        }

        else if (pidFork != 0) { //Parent
            close(sockets[0]);
            if(read(sockets[1], message, strlen(MESSAGE)) == -1) {
                perror("Reading data");
                exit(-1);
            }
            printf("Data: %s\n\n", message);
            close(sockets[1]);
        }

        else { //Child
            close(sockets[1]);
            if(write(sockets[0], MESSAGE, strlen(MESSAGE)) == -1) {
                perror("Writing data");
                exit(-1);
            }
            close(sockets[0]);
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

First I tried to get the file descriptors for a socket pair with a single call to the socketpair function before entering the for loop, such as the commented lines shows, but this only works for the first iteration, from the second on iteration I get a "Bad file descriptor error", the way I made it work was moving the socketpair function call inside the for loop, however the first approach worked for me when using pipes.

So I would like to know why this happens, <strike>Am I making a mistake?
Or Is this a difference between both IPC mechanisms?</strike>

Thanks

**Update:** There's no difference between file descriptors of pipe and socketpair. I thought that it was working with pipes because an error in another part of my full program.
The accepted answer solved my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're closing both ends of the `socketpair` in both parent and child.

In general, use one socket pair or pipe per child process.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the suggestion.

It works if I remove all the calls to the close function, I used that approach because that's what I found in most examples: A close call to both file descriptors in both, child and parent processes.

Also, when using pipes it works even with the all the calls to the close function, just for curiosity: Do you know why?

Comment: @Mkfnx: Do you confirm that it works when you substitute the "socketpair()" system call with "pipe()"? I agree with Larsmans, it's very weird... Isn't there a call to "dup()" or "dup2()"? Bye!

Comment: @Giuseppe I just uploaded an example case of what I thought that my problem was. But now I re-checked my original code and found that I was modifying my messsages in other parts of the program and I wasn't showing error messages, this made me think that it was working, when it wasn't... Sorry for that :(. So the larsmans answer is just right:D Thanks both!